# How to save the data in different files using for loop?

Tags: c++

In the following code for loop returns me 5 values [0,1,2,3,4]. I want to get 5 text files with the name h_0.0, h_1.0, h_2.0, h_3.0, h_4.0 and h_0.0 should store first number of for loop i.e.,0 file h_1.0 should store second number of for loop i.e., 1 and so on.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int *name()
{
    static int n[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        n[i] = i;
    }
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    int *p;
    p = name();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << *(p + i) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well what you want to do, here is some basic solution, for demo,
creating files in current folder:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int* name() {
    static int n[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      n[i] = i;
    }
    return n;
}

int main() {
    int* p;
    p = name();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int fn = *(p + i);
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << fn;
        std::string fname = "h_" + ss.str();
        fname += ".0";
        std::ofstream f(fname.c_str());
        if (f.good()) {
            f << fn;
            cout << "file h_" << fn << ".0 created" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My for loop starts from 0 and it end at 4. In python I will mention h_%s%(i) where i is my loop index. In your solution yout mentioned fname _= ".0" . How to replace it with  for loop index i?Moreover can you please explain what is the purpose of last if statement ? f.good()

Comment: `static int n[5];` and the subsequent `for` loop could be `static int n[] = {1,2,3,4,5};`

Comment: On second thought, `static int n[] = {1,2,3,4,5};`could replace the whole name function. `std::stringstream ss;` and friends could be replaced with `std::string fname = "h_" + std::to_string(fn) + ".0";`

Comment: And that leads to a new thought `static string names[] = {"h_1.0", "h_2.0", ...};` and most of the problem goes away.

Comment: @jerry from your question i conclude as if you want all your files to have .0, say, extension, but if you like .1 .2 etc extensions, you can simply replace apropriate lines with 
fname += "."+ss.str();

cout << "file " << fname << " created" << endl;

Comment: @jerry regarding check on return value of stream descendant good() member function, give us opportunity to check if state of the stream is good, which returns true only if nothing bad happend during, in this case, creation of file, so we dont want to try to operate on an invalid file, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Use filestream.

```
#include <fstream>  // include filestream
#include <sstream>  // for storing anything that can go into a stream
#include <string>

int main()
{

    std::string nameholder;
    std::ofstream outputstream;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        nameholder = "h_";  // reset name every loop
        std::stringstream sstreamholder;   // remake stringstream every loop
        sstreamholder << i;   // store current number in stringstream
        nameholder += sstreamholder.str() + ".0";  // append what sstreamholder currenlty has and the file extension .0
        outputstream.open(nameholder);  // write the filename with the updated name
        outputstream << i << std::endl;  // write the number in the file
        outputstream.close();  // close the file so it's ready for the next open
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But I want to get 5 text files with the name h_0.0, h_1.0, h_2.0, h_3.0, h_4.0 and h_0.0 should store first number of for loop i.e.,0 file h_1.0 should store second number of for loop i.e., 1 and so on

Comment: in that case, just append the number a string for the open(), and work it in that logic. put the open() in a loop along with the update string name.